# Getting error In python3 scapy Module .... Packet Sniffer

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I'm building a sniffing tool using python-3.7 and I got that error when I was trying to use the scapy_http module.

It works fine in python-2.x. The object type is packet[scapy.Raw].load

Code:

```
#!usr/bin/env python
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http

def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)
    #store=Flase(does not store the output in memory)
    #prn= call another  function after one packet or any data is sniffed is sniffed

def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        if packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
            load = packet[scapy.Raw].load
            if "username" in load:
                print(load)
sniff("eth0")
```

ERROR:

```
 File "packet_sniffer.py", line 16, in <module>
    sniff("eth0")
  File "packet_sniffer.py", line 6, in sniff
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 1036, in sniff
    sniffer._run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 989, in _run
    session.on_packet_received(p)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/sessions.py", line 82, in on_packet_received
    result = self.prn(pkt)
  File "packet_sniffer.py", line 14, in process_sniffed_packet
    if "username" in load:
****TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'****
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`packet[scapy.Raw].load` uses `load` from the [scapy.packet.Raw](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.packet.html?highlight=packet#scapy.packet.Raw) class. You are asking python to determine if a string is inside of a bytes object, which is a type error as it says. It's easy to replicate this error:

```
>>> if "word" in b"word":
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Try using `if "username" in str(load):` or `if b"username" in load:` on line 14 instead so there isn't a type mismatch.

---

**Note**: Class hierarchies are confused because of your use of `import scapy.all as scapy`, so `scapy.Raw` is the same as `scapy.Packet.Raw` in your snippet.

Comment: Ross Jacobs .... Now it does not providing any output.
Program is running until  I hit keyboard Interrupt.

Comment: That means that you aren't seeing any packets with the bytes b"username". Most web traffic is encrypted, so this is to be expected.